# Redirect to success in social auth pipelines

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using django social auth to enable oauth. I learnt about handling pipelines, and created a partial pipeline for user login. I am saving the data of user(fetched from third party site) directly to UserSocialAuth model from the user defined pipeline. Now, after storing the data I still don't understand how to return success so that the user is redirected to page in login_redirect_url.

can anyone help me out thanks
this is my pipeline code

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = ( 
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details', 
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid', 
'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user', 
'userauth.social_get_pipeline.get_user')
```

The final pipeline saves the user data successfully. Now what should I return so that remaining part of code is executed successfully and user is redirected to login redirect page

Comment: Can you show your `userauth.social_get_pipeline.get_user` function/class/module ?